# How to find $\angle DEG$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[image]

In $\triangle ABC$,$BD$ is the altitude, $E$ is the orthocenter and $F$ is the circumcenter. A line  perpendicular to $FD$ passing through point $D$ intersect $BC$ at $G$. what is the angle $\angle 
DEG$?
i tried to reflect the orthocenter across $AC$  but couldn't find any useful observations. any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: A GeoGebra sketch indicates that the angle is congruent to $\angle C$.

Comment: This is a well-known problem which can be nicely solved via butterfly theorem

Comment: Consider point $K$ such that $D$ is the midpoint of $EK$ and then construct the parallelogram $EGKN$. Now, it suffices to peove that $N$ lies on $AK$. The last statement follows from the Butterfly theorem, mentioned by @timon92.